# Switch between blending modes in Sketch app Hot key

Tags: sketch-app

I would like to know if there´s a way to switch between blending modes in Sketch app through keyboard (hotkey or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to switch modes right now is a good old fashioned mouse click.

Unfortunately this isn't a feature available (yet) on Sketch as of this posting. Assigning a custom shortcut key is also out of the question since blend modes are not available as menu items.

There is however a healthy community of developers that are working on **Extensions** to improve Sketch functionality. You can put in an idea request at the [Sketch Issue Repository](https://github.com/sketchplugins/plugin-requests/issues) and see if it generates any interest. With any luck, it will be a part of a future release since this is a built-in function of Photoshop already.